# django : already logged in but, request.user.is_authenticated is guest

Tags: django, session, authentication, userinfo

My website use to login function of django.contrib.auth.views.login.

But, some pages has problems about getting user information.

I tried to request.user & request.user.is_authenticated(). then request.user = "admin"(ok) but, request.user.is_authenticated() = guest.. 
And, Staying logged in After close browser. 
what is problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some pages will not show `{{ user }}` but others will, you're most likely not using `RequestContext` in the views where the user isn't available.

You can use a function like django's [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)  to automatically use `RequestContext`.

As for the user staying logged in after closing the browser - that's normal. Your user is identified by a cookie that sits on your browser and is persistent.

Comment: Thank you. I changed to Response(RequestContext from Response(Context.